# Redirecting the user to an external domain in api route in next.js 13

Tags: authentication, redirect, next.js13

I am developing a module of our robust web application. The way authentication works is different then usual thanks to working with modules on different domains therby servers.
In a nutshell how it should work:
when the user provided right credential on the ologin.com it sends teh user to the desired domain with a acct query param what is a JWT token. The module should then verify the token and set the user identifier (firebaseId) as a cookie. After the cookie is set the user should be redirected to the home page without the acct queryParam in the url.

I was trying to handle this with middle ware but I just could not get rid of the queryParam. Now I am trying to set up a login api route but still cannot redirect the user without a query param.

I am not even sure which approach should I use. I am fairly new to Next.js.

```
    export async function POST(req: NextRequest) {
      try {
        const body = await req.json();
        const acct_query = body.acct;
        const acct_cookie = req.cookies.get("acct");
        const firId_cookie = req.cookies.get("firId");
    
        if (!acct_cookie || !firId_cookie) {
          try {
            const token = await checkJWT(
              Array.isArray(acct_query) ? acct_query[0] : acct_query
            );
    
            if (token) {
              const expirationDate = new Date(token.exp! * 1000);
              const expiration = expirationDate.toUTCString();
    
              const response = new NextResponse(
                JSON.stringify({ isLoggedIn: "true" })
              );
    
              response.cookies.set({
                name: "acct",
                value: acct_query,
                path: "/",
                expires: expirationDate,
                sameSite: "none",
                secure: true,
              });
              response.cookies.set({
                name: "firId",
                value: token.firId,
                path: "/",
                expires: expirationDate,
                sameSite: "none",
                secure: true,
              });
    
              redirect("https://google.com");
            } else {
              // return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ isLoggedIn: false }));
              redirect("https://google.com");
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
    
          return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(acct_query));
        } else {
          return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ isLoggedIn: true }));
        }
      } catch (error: any) {
        return new NextResponse(null, {
          status: 500,
          statusText: error.message,
        });
      }
    }
```